# CSS transition conflict each others

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

Im trying to make some react app ,and i have a problem with the css. When i add (is-size-changed) class to the div element(navi) and trying to scrolling transition with the background-color dont work and show the color instant.

when i remove background color class, size its working normally.
CSS code:

```
    .navi {
    height: 10rem;
    /* background: linear-gradient(to top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%,grey 100%); */
    /* background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.9); */
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
    transition: 1s;
    

}

.navi ul{
    display: flex;
    list-style: none;
    justify-content: space-around;
}

.navi .links{
    text-decoration: none;
    margin: 1.4rem 1.4rem 1.4rem 1.4rem;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 150%;
    height: 2.5rem;
    top: 10%;
    padding: 1rem;
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 1rem;
    /* transition: background-color 1s ease;
    transition: height 1s ease; */
}

.links:hover {
    background-color: darkgray;
    padding: 1.3rem;
    transition: 0.8s;
    justify-content: space-around;

}   

.navi-line{
    display: block;
    background-color: red;
    width: 100%;
    height: 5px;
}

.sticky{
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    transition: 2s;

}

.is-color-changed{
    transition: background-color 1s ease;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.9);
}

.is-size-changed{
    /* transition: 1s; */
    transform: scaley(1);
    transition: height 1s ease;
    height: 6rem;
    
    /* background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgb(84, 84, 84) 0%,grey 100%); */

}

.text-color-black a{
    color: black;
}

.text-color-white a{
    color: #fafafa;
    
}


        /* DIFFERENT BACKGROUND */
/* 
.background-color-transition{
    transition: background-color 0.5s ease;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.9);
} */
```

JS/React:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import './Navigation.css';

const Navigation = () => {

    useEffect(() => {
        const header = document.getElementById("header");
        const scrollCallBack = window.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
            if (window.pageYOffset >= header.offsetTop) {
                header.classList.add("sticky", "text-color-white", "is-color-changed", "is-size-changed");
            } else {
                header.classList.remove("sticky", "text-color-white", "is-color-changed", "is-size-changed");
                header.classList.add("text-color-black");

            }
        });
        return () => {
            window.removeEventListener("scroll", scrollCallBack);
        };
    }, []);

    
    return (
        <div id='header' className='navi'>
            <span className='navi-line'></span>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a className='links' href="/heatPump">Термопомпи</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a className='links' href="/heating">Отопление</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a className='links' href="/cooling">Охлаждане</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a className='links' href="/hotWater">Топла вода</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a className='links' href="/energy">Енергия</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a className='links' href="/projects">Проекти</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            
        </div>

    )
}
```

export default Navigation;